# Unknown provider: myFilterProvider <- myFilter,

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-filter

I am learning angular and building a small app.  I am using angular 1.3.1.  I wrote a custom filter and after reading the docs think* that I am using the syntax correctly.  Something is wrong with the dependancy injection, though and I keep getting an "Unknown Provider "  I can't reason what might be wrong anymore.  Please clue me in as to why this is not working, thank you in advance!!

Here is my filter function:

```
angular.module('trimWords', [])
   .filter('trimWords', function(){
      return function(input, words){
         if(isNaN(words)) return input;
         if(input){
           var inputWords = input.split(/\s+/);
              if(inputWords.length > words){
                 input = inputWords.slice(0, words).join(' ') + '...';
               }
           }
           return input;
        };
   });
```

And here is were I declare it in my app and inject it as a dependency:

```
  (function(){
       var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngStorage','ngAnimate','ngRoute',
       'mainController', 'todoService','formController', 'trimWords']);
       angular.module('mainController', [])
             .controller('mainController',['$scope', '$localStorage', 'Todos','trimWords', function($scope, $localStorage, Todos, trimWords){
              $scope.$storage = Todos.initStorage;
              $scope.formData = {};
              $scope.formData.text = ' ';
              $scope.createToDo = Todos.createToDo
              $scope.formData.text = ' ';
              $scope.destroyTodo = Todos.destroyTodo;
        }])
     })();
```

In the network tab, I can see that the file is loading properly. What can I can try to fix this?

Comment: why you are injecting controller as a dependency ?

Comment: yes, you are creating too many modules, which might not be required. Anyways, could you please put the exact error you get in console

Comment: where am i doing that? is this related to the filter function?  Only when I tried to add the filter "trimWords" did I get the error.  Thank you

Comment: @Kulbushan thank you  here is the error from the console:Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$injector/unpr?p0=trimWordsProvider%20%3C-%20trimWords
    at Error (native)
    at http://0.0.0.0:8080/js/vendor/angular.min.js:6:416

Comment: Thank you  Vinett and Kulbhushan,  I was have refactored now... Thanks for commenting on my code

Answer (score 0):

trimWords is a filter, not a service. If you want it to be injected into a controller, then do one of these things:

```
.controller('mainController', function(..., trimWordsFilter, ...) {
```

(note the `Filter` suffix), or

```
.controller('mainController', function(..., $filter, ...) {
    var trimWordsFilter = $filter('trimWords');
```

That said, in the posted code, the controller doesn't use the filter, so there's no reason to inject it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that resolved the provider error.  My intention here was to use the filter in the mainController.  Now I am getting an syntax error when I try to use the filter in my html.  I am using it  this expression : `<h4 ng-bind="todo.text || trimWords: 10"></h4>`.  I am sorry, I thought once you attached the filter to the module you it could be used in expressions...  im sorry... is there anything else I need to do to be able to use it ?  Thank you!!!

Comment: To use a filter, use a **single** vertical bar: `todo.text | trimWords:10`

Comment: thank you... that worked.. sorry, that  i missed that on my own.   thanks again.. i might need more sleep : /